# ip route add -- Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "10.0.0.1" is a garbage

Tags: ip, routing

19.04

The system boots without a default route. Then when I try to add a default route, there is this error.

The error occurs even when I completely clear the routing table.

The ip address is valid :

```
ip a
ethusb: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:e0:4c:61:20:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.120/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global ethusb
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the routing table at boot:

```
 ip r
 10.0.0.0/24 dev ethusb proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.120
```

And here is my attempt to add a default route

```
 ip r add default 10.0.0.1 dev ethusb source 10.0.0.120
 Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "10.0.0.1" is a garbage
```

And the netplan config:

```
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        ethusb:
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
          addresses:
            - 10.0.0.120/24
            - 2604:n:n:n::120/64
          nameservers:
            search: [asus]
            addresses: [10.0.0.120,1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1,"2606:4700:4700::1111","2606:4700:4700::1001"]
```

Comment: Try `ip route add default via 10.0.0.1`?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes that works. Now the route is `default via 10.0.0.1 dev ethusb` Could you explain what's happening. In an answer?

Comment: @ThomasWard -- ah. But it works only in a SSH session. If i attempt through a native terminal session, I still get the error.

Comment: SSH session and Native Terminal both do the same thing you only need to add it ONCE...

Comment: @ThomasWard I am adding only once. After a reboot, I try to add the route in the terminal. No go.  But if I go to another host and SSH in, then I can set the route. However even this is a `sometimes` thing. Sometimes a root session will work first time. I have tried with a couple of devices -- with the same problem. I suspect that underlying is an issue unique to this machine, but I have no idea how to track it down. I look forward to your explanation.

Comment: I think you have something else going on that is handling networking - network manager or Netplan - you shouldn't have to add your route manually...

Comment: @ThomasWard. Netplan. A simple basic configuration I've been using for years on various machines.

Comment: include your netplan config then because I think its wrong if you have to keep adding your routes manually

Comment: @ThomasWard Ah now that would be great! `netplan.yaml` added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if your configuration was set up properly, you wouldn't have to go back and configure the routing by hand - because that's supposed to be defined in the configuration.

Therefore, going to the *core* of your issue, and thanks to you including your `netplan` configuration, I can safely say that **you have an incomplete Netplan configuration for your goals, and that's the problem you're having**.

You *need* to tell the system a routing plan, either a default by specifying the default gateway or with custom routing plans/tables.

When network configuration is done automagically via DHCP/DHCP4, the system is *told* the default gateway and route to use.

When you do *static, manual configuration* of the network, however, you have to actually *specify* the routes yourself - the default route or a specialized routing rule.  In this case, you need to specify the route by specifying your gateway since you're using a default route that points directly through that gateway for all data.

Try using this netplan config, which adds a `gateway4` statement (which is used to specify the default route):

```
network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
       ethusb:
         dhcp4: no
         dhcp6: no
         addresses:
           - 10.0.0.120/24
           - 2604:n:n:n::120/64
         gateway4: 10.0.0.1
         nameservers:
           search: [asus]
           addresses: [10.0.0.120,1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1,"2606:4700:4700::1111","2606:4700:4700::1001"]
```

Comment: Yup that is it. I had been assigning the IP via DHCP reservation and so had dropped the gateway from the config -- started to think I didn't need it. Then my router's DHCP reservation system became muddled (too many changes to cheap router, I guess) so I switched. thx

Comment: @StephenBoston You're welcome, glad we could fix it.  Including the details about how you configure your systems (DHCP vs. Static, Netplan or Network Manager, etc.) helps to solve many of the initial questions, just for the future.  Thanks also for sharing your configs, it helped me to ID the exact error you were running into :)